# How to get user details using passport-SAML in node js

Tags: node.js, authentication, saml, passport-saml

I'm using passport-SAML in node js for SAML authentication.
my SAML Saml Strategy

```
passport.use(new SamlStrategy({
    protocol: 'https://',
    entryPoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=', // SSO URL (Step 2)
    issuer: 'https://.../sp', // Entity ID (Step 4)
    path: '/auth/saml/callback' // ACS URL path (Step 4),
    cert:"fake certificate"

  }, function (profile, done) {
    // Parse user profile data
    done(null, {
      email: profile.email,
      name: profile.name
    })
  })
)
```

And my login code

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('saml', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}))
```

I have cloned project from
[Git hub](https://gist.github.com/fuxingloh/4d6e1caa24237c5870809fe24c47726f)

I'm not able to get user details and also not able to print any console log in
'/login' route. How I can achieve this?